# Overriding DITA XSLT to move related links

Tags: xslt, dita

We are using XSLT to implement the Bootstrap CSS framework, creating a two-column HTML layout for our topic pages. We would like to override the existing DITA XSL (currently DITA-OT 1.8.5) to move the “Related Links/Topics” section from the bottom of the page to the left-column.

In dita2htmlImpl.xsl, I’ve found the below comment (around line 4085) where the related links are pulled in. This tells me that it's all getting pulled into as one large chunk, and I can't figure out how to separate the related links out.

```
<!-- followed by body content, again by fall-through in document order -->
<!-- followed by related links -->
```

I’ve tried to call this template (I've tried by calling both the mode, and a made-up name/ID) to no avail:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/link ')]" mode="related-links:result-group">
```

Does anyone have insight into how I may be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of the DITA-OT, that is not supported anymore. You can use the `args.rellinks` parameter in later versions. You should really upgrade to 2.5.4 or even 3.0.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan, but tha'ts not exactly what I'm looking for. 1.8.5 has args.rellinks. I'm trying to modify the page layout to place the rellinks in a left-hand column. I'm finding this difficult because it appears that the rellinks are flowing through as part of the overall page (as noted in the comment in my original post). I'm not able to separate out the rellinks from the overall flow and am looking for suggestions.